# GDB Breakpoints are inaccurrate on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, gdb, macos-high-sierra

I have been using gdb on Mac recently but sometimes the breakpoints are wrong such that if I assign a breakpoint and run gdb sometimes skips the breakpoint or breaks on the wrong line. Can anyone help me out? I've tried to find the simplest case of the issue below.:

```
Project
|
+-- CMakeLists.txt
|    
+-- include
|    |  
|    +-- A.hpp
|
+-- src 
     |  
     +-- main.cpp
```

A.hpp

```
#pragma once

class A { 
public: 
   A(const char* t){};
};
```

main.cpp

```
1 #include<string>
2 #include"A.hpp"
3 int main(){ 
4   std::string s = "";
5   A a = "";
6   return 0;
7 }
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
1 cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
2
3
4 file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
5 set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
6 
7 add_executable(main ${SOURCES})
8
9 target_include_directories(main PUBLIC include)
```

If I try to set a breakpoint in main.cpp line 4 where the string is assigned and run main in gdb, it stops on line 5.
I think that this happens when standard headers like  are used. If I change line 4 to a simple assignment like int i = 0;, the breakpoint stops on line 4 as expected.

I Have:

Mac Version High Sierra 10.13.6

CMakeVersion: 3.12.0

GDB version: 8.0.1 (installed via homebrew)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Will try to reproduce, but don't have a Mac. What version of clang are you using?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick: Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 0):

> gdb sometimes skips the breakpoint or breaks on the wrong line

In general, this happens when the code is built with optimizations.

I know you've selected `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug`, but perhaps that is still doing an optimized build for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never thought there would still be optimisations even when the build type is debug. I thought it might be because the assigned string is not used but I edited my post above to show gdb stops on other unused assigned variables. Is this issue specific to some standard header types like strings then? Otherwise, is there any way to remove all these optimisations completely so that it stops on string assignments?

Comment: @O.Oyibo Your first step should be to confirm or disprove my guess. `make clean && make` and *observe* the command that is used to compile `main.cpp`. Does it have `-O2` or similar optimization flags, or does it not?

Comment: I ran make clean && make VERBOSE=1 to see the compilation commands and I see no optimisation flags. I only see the -g flag. I had already tried this before posting the initial question so I was wondering if even without any optimisation flags present does it still do some optimisations? From what you're saying It would seem it does but I have no idea why.

Comment: @O.Oyibo Without optimization flags, there should be no optimizations, so my guess is probably wrong.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking do you get the same issue? I just want to check whether it's something wrong with my configuration/gdb setup.